# CakePHP1.3: ionCube Loader + License validation: License invalid

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, ioncube

**What I have :**

I try to setup a  cakephp1.3 application.

In my app, ionCube Loader is used.

**ERROR :**

I am getting below error

"License validation problem: License invalid. Please review the Knowledge Base for information on how to resolve this problem."

**What I tried :**

1.
http://blog.eukhost.com/webhosting/ioncube-installation-globally/

2.

```
<?php
  print_r(get_loaded_extensions());
 ?>
```

its give me :

```
  Array (      
   .......
   .......
   [50] => paradox
   [51] => ionCube Loader
   [52] => Zend Optimizer
)
```

I think "ionCube Loader" is already installed.

**What I want:**

How to resolved below error

"License validation problem: License invalid. Please review the Knowledge Base for information on how to resolve this problem."

Answer (score 2):

Instead of running:

```
<?php
  print_r(get_loaded_extensions());
 ?>
```

Make a PHP file with the contents:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

and check the required components through that, You could also view this link:
http://www.ioncube.com/loader_installation.php

For a little more in-depth overview, and on the same page where you download the ioncube loaders; It gives you a little script which you upload to your webdirectory and it tells you how to install and makes the required checks for you. This little tool is called `Loader Wizard`

http://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php  <-- Loaders

It's worth an attempt, if your still having problems; then contact ioncube support

Answer (score 1):

This suggests that you have some files that are protected, and that the creator of the files has specified that they need a license. The ionCube component will be working fine and doing its job. The provider of the scripts should be able to assist. If you are using the ionCube Encoder and the creator of the files, ionCube support would be able to assist.